# $∀m, ∀n, ∃l | (n<m) ⇒ (l>n)∧(l<m)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to show if the following proposition is true or false and prove my answer. 
$l,m,n$ ∈ {whole numbers} = {$0,1,2,3...$}.

I'm thinking to do a contrapositive on each side. So by putting
the left side $(∀ m, ∀ n, ∃ l | (n < m)) = P$ and right side $((l > n)∧(l < m))$ = Q to show if P⇒Q = ¬Q⇒¬P  and if $¬Q⇒¬P$ is true then $P⇒Q$ is also true.

I'm new to Discrete Math; sorry for my lack of knowledge. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whole numbers... Consider e.g. $(2 < 3)$.

Comment: You probably have one "inferior or equal" or "superior or equal" somewhere which will make your statement true. This version is false for the reason pointed on other comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, for if $m,n$ are consecutive numbers there does not exist some $l$ between $m$ and $n$ which is not equal to $m$ or $n$.